# How to open Node.js command line in ubuntu?

Tags: nodejs

I have completed installed Ruby on Rails on my ubuntu system. I have installed Node.js of **version v0.10.33**. I have try to search the node.js command prompt but not found. May anybody help me how to open node.js cmd prompt in ubuntu ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross posted on SU [How to open Node.js command prompt?](http://superuser.com/q/850281/370509)

Comment: It got a good answer so I think it's OK this time. But please don't do it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary for `node.js` provided by the [`nodejs` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/nodejs/filelist) is called `nodejs`. So, run:

```
nodejs
#or 
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks @muru. If am I write nodejs in terminal, it mean that nodejs cmd line is start working. Am I right ?

Comment: @samzha Yes. You'll get a different prompt (probably `>`).

Answer (score 0):

As muru already mentioned: Since there is a naming conflict with another package "node" is called "nodejs" in Ubuntu. To fix any related errors can add a link to nodejs like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```