# Trouble with node

Tags: 14.04, server, nodejs

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

I just installed nodejs with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

That appears to have all worked correctly

But when I run

```
node -v
```

or

```
node --version
```

It just exits immediately with no output. Not really sure where I should start troubleshooting here..

[image: cap]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open Node.js command line in ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/558306/how-to-open-node-js-command-line-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that debian-based distros already have a 'node' app, i ran into the same issue before, so i installed nodejs (several versions) using nvm.

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps)

Comment: great that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your terminal. That worked for me when I had trouble installing RVM. Please let us know what happens after the restart.

Comment: I had already tried this, but thank you.